# Can't send value to my controller home.php using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**view page**

this is my ajax code block.i have to pass the value from income_date to controller

```
       function incomeDate(income_date)
        {
           // alert(income_date); 
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>home/submit_income",           
            data: {income_date:income_date},
            success: function(res1) 
            {
            }
            });

        }
```

i got the income_date from script

```
       var income_date=document.getElementById("dateVal").value;
```

**function call is here**

```
       incomeDate(income_date);
```

**controller home.php**

```
       function submit_income()
       {
           $income_date=$this->input->post('income_date');
      }
```

Comment: And the problem is ?

Comment: What is the problem and what framework are you using?

Comment: How do you know, are you outputting any of the values anywhere?

Comment: post your error message too!!

Comment: check your `console` what it show `500` or `404`

Comment: You have to use firebug. When you click on the button that calls your AJAX stuff, you see if something is wrong in the console (F12 to open firebug)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
url: "<?php echo base_url();?>home/submit_income",
```

use this:

```
url: "<?php echo site_url();?>home/submit_income",
```

There are high chances that you must have missed the "index.php".(I missed that a lot of times at the beginning of my career!!)

> The base_url() will return something like http://localhost/myproject.
>   Whereas site_url() will return something like http://localhost/myproject/index.php

In CodeIgniter, this is known to cause issues. Try this and kindly clarify further if the issue is something else!!